# How to set referenceSizeForHeaderInSection when the collectionview layout scrolling direction is Horizontal?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

The header gets added properly if I don't specify the scroll direction. But if I specify it, The cells are replaced by the header view. Only the header view will be dispalyed. How to resolve this? Please help!

```
class HongbeiCollectionView: UICollectionView,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDelegate {

var hongbeiData : [Hongbei]!

override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

//        layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: 10)
    super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)



}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    print("Hongbei")
    return hongbeiData.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    print("cell is  being called")
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HongbeiCell", for: indexPath) as! HongbeiCell
   cell.hongbeiButton.sd_setImage(with: URL.init(string: hongbeiData[indexPath.item].video_img ?? ""), for: .normal, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "moren-2"))
     cell.hongbeiButton.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.hongbeiButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0

    print("title is \(hongbeiData[indexPath.item].title!)")
    cell.hongbeiLabel.text = hongbeiData[indexPath.item].title!
    cell.setID(id: hongbeiData[indexPath.item].video_id!)
    cell.hongbeiButton.setTitle("Button \(indexPath)", for: .normal)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
    return CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView{
    print("viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind is called")
    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderForCollectionView", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! HeaderForCollectionView
    headerView.labelHeader.text = "Hongbei"

    return headerView

}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize{
    print("referenceSizeForHeaderInSection")
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 30)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{

    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20.0, bottom: 0, right: 0.0)
}

}
```

If I Specify the `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection's` width less than `collectionview.frame.width` then header view will be displayed first followed by cells.
[image: When the referenceSizeForHeaderInSection is collectionview.frame.width]

[image: When the referenceSizeForHeaderInSection is 200]

Also, If you notice OneyuanZone CollectionView is vertical scrolling and its header is added properly.

Comment: can you explain more what is the issue and what you want to as output ?

Comment: I just want to set a header view for the collection view. I have used the above code. It sets the header properly when I don't specify a scrolling direction. But I want a horizontal scrolling collection view. So if I specify it. The header taking all or specified space of cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in the code below,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize
{
    print("referenceSizeForHeaderInSection")
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 30)
}
```

the width of the header you have given is the the complete `collectionView's` width. This is the reason the cells are not visible. Try reducing it so that you can see the cells as well.

Try using the below code instead.

```
CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width - 50, height: 30)
```

**Edit:**

**View Hierarchy Screenshot:**

[image]

Let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: Please find the added screenshot(2nd) in my question. If I specify it also, Its not helping. The headerview is coming followed by cells.

Comment: Ofcourse this is how it works. Header will come first and then the cells. This is what Header is. What else you require? Please specify clearly.

Comment: You are adding header of a particular section of the collectionview and not just the collectionview. And that is scrollable as you scroll the collectionview.

Comment: I want something like this https://imgur.com/a/5qphP2x. Header has label "New apps we love" and button "See all". And the collectionview can be scrolled horizontally.

Comment: Then you need to add it separately instead of making it a part of the collection view. Is your `collectionview` inside the `tableviewcell`?

Comment: No, Its inside verticalStackView.

Comment: Okay. Then you need to add it separately as a part of `stackView` instead of the `collectionView`.